# What it's default encoding for msbuild?

Tags: c#

I guess he uses the window's code page as the default, but I can't confirm it.
If I modify the code page of the system, the compiled application will cause garbled characters.

Comment: not sure about the default value, but the codepage can be set for the compilation process. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties
You have to ensure your text-editor is saving in the corresponding format also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `codepage` has gone since `Unicode encodings` like  `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` were introduced, But if you want to exactly specify the `codepage` to use, you can specify it using `-codepage` parameter. Read more info [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/codepage-compiler-option).

Comment: When my source text is `GBK` encoded, when the operating system code is `936`, msbuild will not cause garbled characters.I think when MsBuild matches non-Unicode encoded source files, use the encoding of the specific current system code page matching.